Is it possible to fetch all youtube clips generated from a LiveBrodcast, given its VideoId?
After a user has authenticated using OAuth, a server can fetch their recent LiveBroadcasts using the Youtube API (in my case I am using Java, but this is true to all implementation as far as I can tell). Some information is missing from the API- that can (usually) be obtained by performing a GET request for the same URL as the live broadcast shows up on Youtube itself (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/live/MyVidId>)
The issue is, I don't seem to able to get the clips information in either of those methods. The URL to see which clips were made for which video is only available via studio. (https://studio.youtube.com/video/MyVidId/clips).
From server-side, I am unable to access it.
Is this information simply not accessible?

The clips you mention are made by the channel that livestreams or/and other channels?

@BenjaminLoison users that watched the live streams, and clipped parts of it (similar to twitch clips, if you are familiar of it)
